# How to make a grading program using ConsoleIO in Java (***No Scanner***)

Tags: java, console, average

Write a Java application that takes in a number of grade scores (decimals allowed), and computes the average of them. Then print out a letter grade corresponding to the average; either A, B, C, D, or F. See examples below.

Use the following grading scale

At least 90: A
otherwise at least 80: B
otherwise at least 70: C
otherwise at least 60: D
otherwise: F

This is what the output should look like.
**How many grades will you be entering?**
3
**What is the next grade?**
91.5
**What is the next grade?**
90.5
**What is the next grade?**
90
**Here is the average:**
90.66666666666667
This is an A.

here is what I have:

```
  public class Grades1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {


double total;

double grade;
double scores;

ConsoleIO.printLine("How many grades will you be entering?");
grade = ConsoleIO.readDouble();


scores = ConsoleIO.readDouble();

while (grade < 1) {
    ConsoleIO.printLine("you must enter a grade");
    ConsoleIO.readDouble();
  }

ConsoleIO.printLine("What is the next grade?");
  score = ConsoleIO.readDouble();


 total = ()


    ConsoleIO.printLine("Your grade is ");
    if (total > 90){
        ConsoleIO.printLine("A");
    }
    else if (total > 80) {
        ConsoleIO.printLine("B");
    }
    else if (total > 70) {
                ConsoleIO.printLine("C");
    }
    else if (total > 60) {
        ConsoleIO.printLine("D");
    }
    else {
        ConsoleIO.printLine("F");
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Assuming your ConsoleIO is http://euclid.nmu.edu/~mkowalcz/cs120/javadocs/ConsoleIO.html, it's just a matter of replacing nextDouble and nextInt from Scanner with readDouble and readInt from ConsoleIO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943348/how-to-calculate-the-average-grade-of-the-values-from-an-array/39943725 can be adapted for that

Comment: Please indent your code properly; it will make a lot of difference in trying to debug it.

Comment: What is your problem with this code? Does it have a compile error? Does it have a runtime exception? In those two cases, please give us the full error/exception, including any stack trace. Is the output wrong? In this case, please show us the input, the expected output, and the actual output. Please do not handicap the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your JVM has any console attached to. `System.console();` returns the unique `Console` object associatedwith the current Java virtual machine, **if any**.

**`System.console()`** returns a `java.io.Console`, which is the proper way to invoke it since Java5 *(more or less..)*

So you may be hitting a nullPointer if you execute it on a JVM without console.

That said, this is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{  
    double total=0, score=0;
    int grades=0;
    Console con = System.console(); 
    PrintWriter w = con.writer(); //beware here (NPE)

    while (grades < 1) 
    {
       w.println("How many grades will you be entering? Minimum is 1");
       String numGrades = con.readLine();
       grades = isNumeric(numGrades)?Integer.parseInt(numGrades):-1;
       if (grades<0)
          w.println("Please enter a valid value. You shithead.");
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<grades;i++) 
    {
       w.println("Enter score for grade nº"+(i+1));
       String scoreS = con.readLine();
     
       if (isNumeric(scoreS)) 
          score += Double.parseDouble(scoreS);
       else {
          w.println("Come on man...not again.. Please enter a numeric value..");
          --i;
       }
    }

    total = (score/grades*1D);
    char finalG = getFinalGrade(total);
    w.printf("Your score average is: %f - Grade : %s", total, finalG);
}
```

---

```
public static boolean isNumeric(final String str) 
{
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) 
        return false;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) 
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) 
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static char getFinalGrade(double total)
{
    if (total >= 90)
       return 'A';
    if (total >= 80) 
       return 'B';
    if (total >= 70) 
       return 'C';
    if (total >= 60) 
       return 'D';
    
    return 'F';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do have a ConsoleIO page that the program references. I replaced w.printf with ConsoleIO.printLine. Thank you again! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This is my first time going to stack overflow for help with a question, I am quite new to coding (as you may have noticed :) ). I think it is really amazing that you are willing to take the time to answer questions and provide solutions to problems. Without your help I would still be wondering how to format the counter and my code would be very long and unorganized. Thank you so much again for your help! I will focus on keeping my lines indented and organized properly.

Comment: @TylerKlasell dude, seriously...I cannot show in words how I feel right now, I am who thanks you. I was feeling kinda down this week and your comment just made my day. This seems stupid but I appreciate so much your comment I cannot describe it. Best luck in life mate. (p.s: I updated the answer, corrected some errors and added extra salt to it). See you around mate!! : )